# Downloading files using DCC

Tags: java, irc

I found [a very nice library written in Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/moepii/) to create the an IRC client in Java but I can't find any information regarding the DCC download option.

I'm looking for anybody that can link me article/tips/source code on how to handle this.

[Definition found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Client-to-Client): 
DCC connections can be initiated in two different ways:

1. The most common way is to use CTCP to initiate a DCC session. The CTCP is sent from one user, over the IRC network, to another user.
2. Another way to initiate a DCC session is for the client to connect directly to the DCC server. Using this method, no traffic will go across the IRC network (the parties involved do not need to be connected to an IRC network in order to initiate the DCC connection).

Another nice page to [explain DCC protocol](http://www.kvirc.de/docu/doc_dcc_connection.html): 
DCC Transfer
..."The DCC transfer part is different for every DCC subprotocol, but it always happens over a direct client to client TCP connection."...

Got part of an answer: The [pircBot](http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/index.html) is using this kind of functionality  Build-in functionnality written in JAVA to get file send over DCC.

- In the JavaDoc 'receive'

  public void receive(File file, boolean resume)

Answer (score 2):

DCC is a part of the CTCP section, the IRC RFC only seems to define the handshake part but not the actual mechanics of transmission. I imagine its just a socket though.

http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/dccspec.html

Comment: I think you're right, in the doc: "Create a socket, bind it to INADDR_ANY, port 0, and make it passive (a listening socket)..." thx for the link

Comment: The answer to this existing question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951277/irc-dcc-receive-files/35316166?noredirect=1#comment64490773_35316166